# Are classes build of struct internally?

Tags: class, struct

Can we implement class using struct (with function pointers for methods) ?

Answer (score 2):

It *can* be done. In fact, in the very, very early days, C++ was implemented with a pre-processor that generated C code which then got compiled by the C compiler. So if you have a language which has structs and function pointers but not classes, it *can* be done. It isn't particularly pretty.